# opening all detached screen sessions in one command on linux

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

is there a way to open/attach to all detached screen sessions on linux in one command/script?
typically I have the following flow to open a session:

```
#see all screen sessions
screen -rD 
#attach to one screen session
screen -rD screen_name
```

Comment: explain what you are trying to achieve. You can't open more than one session because you operate on only one terminal and for more sessions you need more terminals. Now there could be a way to union all sessions, but I don't know how.

Comment: @akostadinov: I usually have aroun 6 screen sessions and I would have to type in 7 commands to check on all of them, one for listing the session names, 6 for attaching to them in 6 new terminals.  is there a way to simplify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to have only one screen session with many terminals within. You create a new terminal with Ctrl+a+c, then you switch through them with `Ctrl+a+<space>` or `<backspace>` or a number.
I don't think there is an easier way if you do that manually. If you spawn sessions with a script, you may try using `-X` to make screen open a new window in an existing session and execute commands in there. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1236612/520567) is close to what you would need. You will need to make sure you name your screen session in a way, you can reference it later unambiguously.

Answer (score 0):

**This can be done with a bash script like this:**

```
#!/bin/bash

for s in $(screen -ls | grep tached | awk '{print $1}' | tac)
do
  screen -d -r "$s"
done
```

**Here's how it works:**

1. **Lists detached sessions:** `screen -ls | grep tached`
2. **Reverses order (newest first):** `tac`
3. **Iterates through sessions:** `for s in ...`
4. **Reattaches to each session:** `screen -d -r "$s"`